# How to make wss4j to not create expires element in soap header

Tags: cxf, ws-security, wss4j

Is there any option in wss4j or cxf that controls whether `<expires>` element from ws-security is included in SOAP header.

What I want to achieve is that SOAP header contains only `<created>` element, e.g.

```
<wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-2" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <wsu:Created>2011-12-07T14:39:03Z</wsu:Created>
</wsu:Timestamp>
```

I'm using wss4j 1.5.10 and cxf 2.3.x

Note that [xsd schema](http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd) for timestamp has

```
<xsd:element ref="wsu:Expires" minOccurs="0"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed the same thing and wasn't able to find an answer anywhere.
At the end I studied the source and did it extending the `WSS4JOutInterceptor` and rewriting the method `decodeTimeToLive` this way:

```
@Override
public int decodeTimeToLive(RequestData reqData) {
     return 0;
}
```

Maybe not beautiful, but it worked for me.